Google Sites does not give me TXT record
I'm trying to publish my Google Sites using a custom domain placed in Cloudflare.
I have a Google Sites with a custom domain, in Google Search Console I added the property which is verified. My domain is in Cloudflare, in domain's DNS I added a CNAME with name: www, content: ghs.googlehosted.com, Proxy: DNS only.
When I verify the property in Google Search Console it does not give me the TXT record, so I can't add it to Cloudflare DNS Records.
Does anybody know how I can get the TXT record of the verified property?

Found it:
Go to Google Search Console -> Settings -> Users and permissions
Then select the user associated with the verified property, click at the 3 vertical points (More actions), and hit "Ownership verification details",
there you will see the value of TXT record.
